# Rotate and Move an half-circle Matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation, move

I plot an half-circle and I rotate it with :

```
t=linspace(0,pi,1000);
x=r*cos(t);
y=r*sin(t);
h=plot(-2+x,y);
rotate(h,[0 0 -1],1,[0.5 3.71 0]);
```

now, I would like to move/shif the half-circle from the center , such that the half-circle changes position but I want that it maintains also the rotation done.

Who can help me?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You can shift stuff around by adding or subtracting values from x and y.

Comment: ok,but after the rotation , how can i subtracting values?

Comment: Check out the `hgtransform` object. If you set your object's parent to be a hgtransform, then you can use hgtransform function to rotate, translate, scale, etc. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hgtransform.html

Comment: @MZimmerman6 - the rotate docs state that the command does actually change the XData YData etc.

Comment: there's a kind in matlab to rotate and move the object keeping track of the values? such that i can move the object where i want?

Comment: You can edit them no problem! Try this: `h=plot(1:100); set(h,'ydata',get(h,'ydata')*10);`. But probably not a very useful solution. I think hgtransform is best suited. (EDIT: I was replying to a post which has since been removed)

Comment: thanks, you think about an animation, where you at the first step doing the rotation of the half-circle, after you want that this object that you have obtained moves in other position with other center. how you could do?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below; the documentation for `hgtransform` has some example on using the function for animation. The same principal (a for loop with some changes to the figure data and a `drawnow` command in it) can be applied to any of the other answers, too.

Answer (score 2):

To shift for example 10 units in the x direction and 5 in the y direction:

```
set(h,'XData',get(h,'XData')+10)
set(h,'YData',get(h,'YData')+5)
```

As you see, it's done by modifying the properties of the h object

Answer (score 0):

Disregard my above comments, you can actually shift data around after it has been plotted. You can modify the XData and YData values as long as you have a handle to the plot that you created

Do something like this

```
clc; close all; clear all;
t=linspace(0,pi,1000);
r = 5
x=r*cos(t);
y=r*sin(t);
h=plot(-2+x,y);
rotate(h,[0 0 -1],1,[0.5 3.71 0]);
xShift = 5;
yShift = 5;
set(h,'XData',get(h,'XData')+xShift)
set(h,'YData',get(h,'YData')+yShift)
```

Comment: Please consider accepting or upvoting an answer on the page so people know which answer you used is someone else has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional answer to demonstrate hgtransform, the others will work well too.

```
t=linspace(0,pi,1000);
x=r*cos(t);
y=r*sin(t);
h=plot(-2+x,y);
rotate(h,[0 0 -1],1,[0.5 3.71 0]);

hgt=hgtransform('parent',gca);
set(h,'parent',hgt);
Tx = makehgtform('translate',[10 -5 0]); % translate +10 x, -5 y, 0 z
set(hgt,'Matrix',Tx);
drawnow;
```

You could also potentially use the hgtranform to do the rotation at the same time, but it might take a bit of fiddling around to get the axis origin to work as you have above:

```
RxTx = makehgtform(xrotate',0.5,'yrotate',3.71,'translate',[10 -5 0]);
set(hgt,'Matrix',RxTx);
drawnow;
```